# endless loop adding a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods

I am a little confused, and after countless attempts and read several articles I decided to write.
my problem is that if you call a method from a class (xml) and it is aimed at viewcontroller all goes well
but if I might add [self.view add...] it back to the top reloading the viewDidLoad of the viewController class entering into an endless loop.

this is what I do

class (ViewController)
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class  XMLStuff;

@interface skiSpeedViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) XMLStuff *xml;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    xml.skiSpeedC = self;

    GpsStuff *gps = [GpsStuff alloc];
    [gps init];
}
```

gps.m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        xml = [XMLStuff alloc];
}
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
     [xml lon:newLocation.coordinate.longitude lat:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

xml.h

```
#import "skiSpeedViewController.h"

@class skiSpeedViewController;

@interface XMLStuff : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) skiSpeedViewController *skiSpeedC;
```

.m

```
   @synthesize skiSpeedC;

- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
NSLog(@"--%@", self.skiSpeedC); // Return (null)
[self.skiSpeedC riceviDic:datiMeteo];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
    -(void)riceviDic:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictMeteo {
        datiMeteo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dictMeteo];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    classViewController *skiSpeedC = [classViewController alloc];
    [skiSpeedC riceviDic:datiMeteo];
}
```

You are creating a new instance of `classViewController` every time. Your "xml" class (XMLStuff?) should have a pointer to the view controller and be calling the `riceviDic` method on that instance.

You're getting an infinite loop because when you allocate the XML object in viewDidLoad, it too starts parsing the XML, then creates more XML objects, which then create more viewControllers...

So, add a property to XMLStuff of type classViewController, and when you create it in viewDidLoad:

```
xml.skiSpeedC = self;
```

Then, in parserDidEndDocument:

```
- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [self.skiSpeedC riceviDic:datiMeteo];
}
```

**UPDATE**

OK, after your edit things look very different - you seem to have introduced a new class - GpsStuff, which has its *own* instance of XMLStuff (and a dodgy looking init method which I assume you haven't copied in properly?). Which one is actually parsing your document? XMLStuff in your view controller, or in GPSStufF? I'm guessing the one in GPSStuff, which you haven't set the `skiSpeedC` property for. I was previously assuming that you were calling everything from your view controller.

Why not remove the creation of a new XMLStuff object from GPSStuff, and when you create GPSStuff in your view controller, pass the `xml` object you've created into it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GpsStuff *gps = [[GpsStuff alloc] init];
    XMLStuff *xml = [[XMLStuff alloc] init];
    xml.skiSpeedC = self;
    gps.xml = xml;
    [xml release];
}
```

Also, the `skiSpeedC` property should probably not be `retain`, since it is essentially a delegate assignment and the view controller is not going to be released before you release the xml parser.

As a note, by convention you should be initializing objects like this:

```
GPSStuff *gps = [[GPSStuff alloc] init];
```

Not on two lines. You want what is returned from `init` to be assigned to your variable.

Comment: I would say that we are half way, the infinite loop is gone, although I do not understand why, could you explain it? but now I'm missing something, if I put [self.view addToSubview: something]; nothing is displayed. example: -(void)riceviDic:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictMeteo{labelBox = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(36, 43, 161, 93)];[labelBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];[self.view addSubview:labelBox];} inside the viewController class

Comment: I tried as you say, but the label does not appear red, mind if I use the same code inside the vieDidLoad all goes well - EDIT: even if i add  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:labelBox];

Comment: I realized I had not checked whether the method was called or not, it seems that [self.skiSpeedC riceviDic: datiMeteo] does not work

Comment: perfect! we were able to make it work! even if I did not understand what happens when we write xml.skiSpeedC. But I believe that my knowledge level is not yet high enough to fully understand these strings